# (CKEditor) Window is not defined ReactJS While Implementing

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I would like to implement CKEditor into my react project. However, I received an error while trying to load it. I have been following all the official documentation. I have no idea why, anyway here is my code

```
import React from 'react';

class MyEditor extends React.Component {
    state = {loading: true};

    componentDidMount() {
        this.CKEditor = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react");
        this.ClassicEditor = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic");
        this.setState({ loading: false }); 
    }

    render() {
        return ({this.CKEditor && (<this.CKEditor editor={this.ClassicEditor} data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
                onInit={ editor => {
                    // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                    console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
                } }
                onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
                    const data = editor.getData();
                    console.log( { event, editor, data } );
                } }/>)})
    }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

I receive this following error

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
>       at Object. (/Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/project/test/node_modules/
>   ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/dist/ckeditor.js:5:244 Module._compile
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30 Module._extensions..js
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10 Module.load
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32 tryModuleLoad
>   internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12

I really appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is it rendered server side? NextJs?

Comment: sure, its NextJs

Comment: if remix brought you here, export the CKEditor component from a file with extension `*.client.tsx` to prevent it from getting rendered on the server

Comment: or maybe wrap in <ClientOnly>

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a working example with NextJS and React Hooks. We can take advantage of `useRef` to hold on to the Editor instances.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function MyEditor () {
  const editorRef = useRef()
  const [editorLoaded, setEditorLoaded] = useState(false)
  const { CKEditor, ClassicEditor } = editorRef.current || {}

  useEffect(() => {
    editorRef.current = {
      // CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'), // depricated in v3
      CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react').CKEditor // v3+
      ClassicEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic')
    }
    setEditorLoaded(true)
  }, [])

  return editorLoaded ? (
    <CKEditor
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data='<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>'
      onInit={editor => {
        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
        console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor)
      }}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData()
        console.log({ event, editor, data })
      }}
    />
  ) : (
    <div>Editor loading</div>
  )
}
```

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref):

> `useRef` returns a mutable ref object whose `.current` property is initialized to the passed argument (`initialValue`). **The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.**

Comment: I ended up making a custom hook for this, which you can find here: https://gist.github.com/arcdev1/aba0fcea9f618de42ca399e3266f42aa

Comment: Perfect, Bill. =)

Comment: If you are using CKEditor 3.0.0 and above, the default import was removed so change:
```CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'),```
Into: 
```CKEditor: require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react').CKEditor,```

Comment: Thanks @omerts ... updated the code in my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing server side rendering then you need to load your CKeditor dynamically, because it interacts with the DOM thus, on server since there is no browser it throws this Error.

```
 class MyEditor extends React.Component {
  state = { loading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.CKEditor = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react");
    this.ClassicEditor = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic");
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }

  render() {
    return this.CKEditor ? (
      <this.CKEditor
        editor={this.ClassicEditor}
        data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
        onInit={editor => {
          // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
          console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
        }}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          console.log({ event, editor, data });
        }}
      />
    ) : (
      <div>Editor loading</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but I got an error './components/TextEditor.js
SyntaxError: /Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/project/test/components/TextEditor.js: Unexpected token (1:13)'

FYI I am doing SSR with NextJs

Comment: can you share the exact code after the change? I think i wrote from as 'form' in the first line. can you recheck that

Comment: hi, I have edit the code above. Please kindly check it. Thank you

Comment: There is a typo on the imprt it should be from and not form

Comment: Hi, I have fixed the typo but its still error './components/TextEditor.js
SyntaxError: /Users/bobbyjulian/Desktop/project/test/components/TextEditor.js: Unexpected keyword 'this' (13:17)'

Comment: @RadenBagus check now i missed some brackets, it should work now. Just make sure the dependencies are installed

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic import will solve this issue